# What's the meaning of Sign function applied to matrices with MatrixFunction?

Tags: functions, matrix

I have noticed that `Sign` function can be very well applied to matrices using `MatrixFunction`. It even works on some zero divisors, such as `{{1,1},{1,1}}`. But how does it work and what is its meaning?

For instance, I noticed that when applied to split-complex numbers in matrix form it takes 9 possible values: $0,1,-1, j, -j,  1/2+j/2,1/2-j/2, -1/2+j/2, -1/2-j/2$. This is in contrast to complex numbers, where the set of values is infinite.

When applied to dual numbers, it gives 5 different values.

The usual rule $\text{sign } (AB)=\text{sign }A\cdot \text{sign } B$ still holds though.

It can give totally complicated results, for instance, when applied to a tessarine $1+i+j$:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
$Pre = If[FreeQ[#, J], #, Module[{tmp},
     tmp = Evaluate[
        MatrixFunction[Function[J, #], {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]] // 
       FullSimplify;
           tmp /. {{a_, b_}, {b_, a_}} -> a + J b]] &;
Sign[J + 1 + I]
```

It produces:
$\left(\frac{1+\frac{i}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{i}{2}\right) j+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{i}{10}\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+(1+2 i)\right)$

Comment: `But how does it work ` is it not just element by element? `Sign[{{1, -8}, {1, 7}}]` gives `{{1, -1}, {1, 1}}` so the `Sign` was applied to each element of the matrix? resulting in new matrix with only `1` and `-1` in it.  but may be I am overlooking something deeper in your question.

Comment: @Nasser no, it can give totally complicated values. For instance, in tessarines (complex+split-complex numbers) it gives $\text{sign }(1+i+j)=\left(\frac{1+\frac{i}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{i}{2}\right) j+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{i}{10}\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+(1+2 i)\right)$

Comment: @Nasser in your example you do not use ```MatrixFunction```. Without it, a function applies to a matrix element-wise.

Comment: @Nasser you should use ```MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, -8}, {1, 7}}]```. In this case, the result is (surprisingly) 1 (your matrix is positive).

Comment: @Nasser But try ```MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, -8}, {-1, 7}}]``` and you will get a more complicated result $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{3}{\sqrt{17}} & -\frac{8}{\sqrt{17}} \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{17}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Comment: `Sign` does work element by element. But there is a $Pre here and some magical handling of the symbol `J` so it's not obvious what to expect in the result. You might want to break this down into separate steps to understand exactly where it departs from expectations.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau separate step:`MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, -8}, {-1, 7}}]`

Comment: The documentation has examples where a symbolic scalar function is used, e.g., `MatrixFunction[f, {{1, -8}, {-1, 7}}]`. As long as no derivatives of the scalar function occur, substituting `Sign` for `f` will yield the results you see.

Comment: @CarlWoll is there a link or something? I did not find.

Comment: Look at the first and last examples of the `Generalizations & Extensions` section.

Comment: @CarlWoll these are examples of 2x2 matrices, not a general form for any rank.

Answer (score 3):

```
Format[a[n_, m_]] := Subscript[a, Row[{n, m}]]

mat = Array[a, {2, 2}];

(sgnmat = MatrixFunction[Sign, mat] // FullSimplify)
```

[image]

```
(sgnmat2 = MatrixFunction[#/Abs[#] &, mat] // FullSimplify)
```

[image]

```
MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, -8}, {1, 7}}]

(* {{1, 0}, {0, 1}} *)

% === (sgnmat /. Thread[Flatten[mat] -> Flatten[{{1, -8}, {1, 7}}]])

(* True *)

%% === (sgnmat2 /. Thread[Flatten[mat] -> Flatten[{{1, -8}, {1, 7}}]])

(* True *)

MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, -8}, {-1, 7}}] // Simplify

(* {{-(3/Sqrt[17]), -(8/Sqrt[17])}, {-(1/Sqrt[17]), 3/Sqrt[17]}} *)

% === (sgnmat /. Thread[Flatten[mat] -> Flatten[{{1, -8}, {-1, 7}}]])

(* True *)

%% === (sgnmat2 /. 
    Thread[Flatten[mat] -> Flatten[{{1, -8}, {-1, 7}}]] // Simplify)

(* True *)
```

Comment: This rises a question, what is `Abs` when applied to matrices.

Comment: @Anixx - For an input of `{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}` I get a result of `{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}` for all three evaluations.